# Disable IE menu while displaying a custom dialog

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, alert

Is there a way to disable IE's UI (e.g. the File Menu) when showing a custom dialog/window? What I'm after is similar to what happens when you `alert()` something: the browser UI cannot be interacted with behind the alert box.

Comment: Hey this is a community, I'll rephrase your question, feel free to tell me if that's what you meant.

Comment: Please clarify your question; are you saying that when you use alert() in Javascript, you are unable to utilize the I.E. Menu Bar?

Comment: And here's +1. This answer does not deserve to be down-voted

Comment: My guess was that he wanted to deliberately disable the browser's UI without having to `alert`. Whilst you can sort of do that with showModalDialog, it's a severe usability degradation and a sure sign that you are doing something very wrong.

Comment: @bobince: agreed, and edited to reflect that. I'm also going with the Dupe the OP created here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787817/mouse-click-limit-problem-like-a-alert where (judging from the comment) I *think* it's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called a dialog, and [JQuery has a good one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: I'll have to agree with Josh. You wont be able to do what you want with a native dialog (such as an alert or a confirm box)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you want isn't going to be possible. `alert` and `confirm` both (1) pause the currently executing javascript and (2) act as modal dialogs for the browser. There is no other way to simulate this behavior.