# mouse click limit problem, like a alert()

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable IE menu while displaying a custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787625/disable-ie-menu-while-displaying-a-custom-dialog)

alert Function is executed, you can not click on the menu of Internet Explorer.

I would like to implement these features.

please , give me hint.

and sorry, i can't speak english well..

Comment: OK this is the *exact* text from your question an hour ago (before edits to improve it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787625/clicking-ie-menu-while-displaying-a-pop-up-alert-confirm

Answer (score 0):

```
alert ( "You have to close this to click anywhere else" );
```

This will prevent the user from clicking anywhere inside the browser window.

Comment: but,i don't want to  use alert function...
I want to use the function I created the dialog...